# Remove Certain Alphanumeric Characters from a String in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, replace, strip

I have to validate a string based on first alpha-numeric character of the string.  Certain characters can be part of the string but if they are at beginning then they have to ignored.

For example:

```
---  BATest- 1   --
```

should be:

```
BATest-1
```

How do I remove dashes from beginning and end but not from middle?

To add to my question: can the first alphanumeric character decide if following alphanumeric characters are to be removed or not?

I.e. If `A` then nothing would need to be removed and throw a validation error; and yet if `B` then strip the string as mentioned above.

Comment: You want to remove the dash characters from the front and end of the string?  And you want to remove space characters also?  And FWIW: you should post the properly-formatted code that you've written to try to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, need to remove  dashes from front and end, space from whole string.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. You say the problem you're trying to solve is "[validating] a string based on [its] first alpha-numeric character," but the question you've asked is how to remove dashes from a string. The latter isn't necessarily a good solution to the former, but it's hard to help you when you haven't shown us the code you've written so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]" including the links at the bottom, and "[mcve]". We'd like to see your effort toward solving the problem. Without that it looks like you're asking us to write the code for you, which is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

You asked to remove the dashes from the beginning and the end:

```
"--- BATest- 1 --".gsub(/^-+|-+$|\s/, "")
# => "BATest-1"
```

Comment: @user3075906: Your expected result (`'BATest-1'`) doesn't contain a whitespace in the middle. May be a typo?

Comment: No, its not. Remove space from everywhere. Dash from start and end.

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /
    --+ # Match at least two hyphens
    |   # or
    \s  # Match a space
    /x  # Free-spacing regex definition mode

'--- BATest- 1 --'.gsub r, ""
  #=> "BATest-1"
```